# Why would I need JobLauncherTestUtils and JobRepositoryTestUtils in Spring Batch Testing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Why would I need to use **JobLauncherTestUtils and JobRepositoryTestUtils** instead of **JobLauncher and JobRepository** in testing Spring Batch project? What are their differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JobLauncherTestUtils` has the following advantages:

- Ability to run a single step in a job
- Ability to get a unique `JobParameters` instance for each run

`JobRepositoryTestUtils` has the following advantages:

- Utility methods to create `JobExecution` instances which can be used as test fixtures
- Utility methods to remove specific `JobExecution`s or cleanup the entire job repository (useful after or before each test)

Please refer to the javadoc of each class for more details.